# Nginx regex vhost pattern ends up as PHP server name

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx server definition with a regex match, like this:

```
server_name ~^(?<vhost>[a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com$;
root /var/www/example/$vhost;
access_log /var/log/nginx/$vhost.example-access.log;
```

That all works nicely, however, this domain hosts various PHP projects using fastcgi and PHP-FPM, which receive values like this in `$_SERVER`:

```
SERVER_NAME => "~^(?<vhost>[a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com$"
HTTP_HOST   => "myhost.example.com"
```

As you can see, the regex pattern is put into `SERVER_NAME` rather than the string that it matched. That seems a bit buggy to me, and also represents a security risk in that it is revealing unnecessary details (in other configs I'm matching a specfic set of names rather than a wildcard).

You might say "use HTTP_HOST instead of SERVER_NAME" - if only it was that simple - there are libraries which expect SERVER_NAME to (no surprise) contain the name of the server. I can't really see a good use case for this behaviour.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to the rubber-duck effect of writing this question, I found a solution.

Nginx's stock `fastcgi_params` file contains the line:

```
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

which is what causes that value to appear in `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` in the PHP environment.

I changed that to use the [$host variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host):

```
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $host;
```

and my problem went away. I'd be interested to know if there are any downsides of this approach.

Comment: The only downside to this approach is as it's relying on $host variable, which means it can be overwritten by user if he sends HTTP_HOST header. You can test this using curl: `curl --header "HOST: google.com" http://yourdomain/yourpage.php` and in yourpage.php put: `<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>` You will see google.com

Answer (score 2):

```
server_name  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.example\.com$;
set $server_name_full $subdomain.example.com;


location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name_full;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.